# Which native APIs from Apple and Android devices can Appcelerator access which Phonegap cannot?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, titanium, appcelerator

I am aware of Appcelerator and Phonegap's differences with regards to their approach in creating cross device/platform applications for Android and iOS.  I believe one of Appcelerators advantage is that it has access over the device's API, correct me if I am wrong but isn't Phonegap also capable of accessing the device's API?  My question is  if both of them has access to the device's API, then what advantage does Appcelerator have over Phonegap in terms of API coverage?  Which native APIs from Apple and Android devices can Appcelerator access which Phonegap cannot?

Comment: both platforms keep adding new features to their API. So there is no clear answer for this. Both of them have a *lot* covered.

Comment: @topener as of their latest release which of the two has an advantage over the other in terms of native api access.  These two technologies are both great, Im just curious because I have'nt yet came across any indepth comparison between their native api  support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the typical PhoneGap application, you're trying to mimic the native GUI elements in JavaScript, most likely with something like the Sencha Touch framework. However, with Titanium (Appcelerator is the company, Titanium is the product), you're using Native GUI elements.

To answer your question, when you're developing a simple application in PhoneGap, you're not using the native Table View, Tab View, Image View, etc. Instead, you're using JavaScript that tries to mimic those controls. So, in even the simplest of cases, you're not using native APIs with PhoneGap.

Comment: I believe that is true for the user interface part but how about the camera controls,volume controls, map, sqlite integration etc. Doesnt those functionalities require phonegap to have access to the devices native API?

Comment: @royjavelosa those API's are also available on Titanium. Not sure about it, but it could even be faster on Titanium as it is native, and not mimicking.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're able to write your own native code for either Android or iOS using PhoneGap, I don't think there are actual limitations in terms of API coverage beyond what comes with it out of the box. I just finished writing a plugin for PhoneGap that allows me to access the orientation gyros (ie yaw, pitch, roll) on Android because it didn't have one.  Since PhoneGap fires up your class on initialization, you're able to inject whatever code you need before/after executing the super.loadUri statement.

PhoneGap is simply a wrapper that makes it easier to separate your presentation layer from the native device code by automatically loading up an html file in a chromeless browser and then listening for specific requests made from the browser back to the native code (ie, the plugins PhoneGap ships with).  You're free to add additional native code around the PhoneGap wrapper.

Comment: Those are the basic native APIs that we all know phonegap and other mobile web frameworks support, what Im interested in are those which are out of Phonegap and Titanium's scope out of the box.  Are there no documented list of not supported native APIs from both of them or at least a comparison?